# javascript scroll to position on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript that I am trying to get to work but

I was able to collect the y Axis by using

`var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();`

but I am unable to scroll to the same position in the refreshed url.

Because there is no error showing I cant figure out what is causing my script not to work.

```
$(".refreshfix").click(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();

  var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var address = $(this).attr("sorttype");

  // window.location.replace(address);
  // window.location.href = address;
  // window.location = address;
  // document.location.reload(true)
  window.location.assign(address);

  $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
  // window.scrollTo(0, tempScrollTop);
  console.log(tempScrollTop)

});
```

I tried variations of using to use scrollTo and scrollTop as well as.  I commented out some of the code that I have tried but its not working.

My best guess is that this new page that it has moved to does not has lost the variable "tempScrollTop" but I have not idea how to transport the variable to be used in the next page. I have found some reference on stackoverflow that allows me to scroll to specific position but none that gives any tips on scrolling to position on a refreshed page. Am new to JavaScript, does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thank you

Comment: If its a page refresh your variable will be destroyed. You can pass it through query string, through a server side call or use anchor tags to scroll to a certain place in your refreshed page

Comment: The variable is lost upon the page refresh. What you can do is add a name attribute to the anchor, like <a name="something" ...> and pass the value to the new url: window.location.assign(address + '#something');
This way browser will scroll the page automatically to the position of that anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page refreshes, it does because of `window.location.assign()`, all you variables are gone in the nothingness. A new page loads.

But you can use [`localStorage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store/retreive values. That is quick and easy.

```
// On load, get the value if exist
var scroll_y = parseInt( localStorage.getItem("scroll_y") );

// If there is a value, scroll!
if(!isNaN(scroll_y)){
  $(window).scrollTop(scroll_y);
  console.log(scroll_y);
}

// On click, store the value.
$(".refreshfix").click(function(e){
  event.preventDefault();

  var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var address = $(this).attr("sorttype");

  localStorage.setItem("scroll_y",tempScrollTop);
  window.location.assign(address);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, what this does it that it brings the scroll_y over to the new page, which is successful because I did a console log to confirm that it has been moved over, but the window is not changed.  I used the below to scroll the window downwards but they wouldnt work.  var scroll_y = localStorage.getItem("scroll_y")

  $(window).scrollTop(scroll_y);

  // window.scrollTo(0, scroll_y); Do you have any ideas to move the window using the scroll_y?

Comment: mmm... It's possible you have to parse it to a number... Using `parseFloat(scroll_y)` or `parseInt(scroll_y)`. Try it and I'll update if it works.

Comment: Thanks but I tried and unfortunately it doesnt. I used var scroll_y = parseFloat(scroll_y) to change it. I am wondering if I need additional libraries to do that. :(

Comment: I updated... Since you `parseInt()`... The condition has to change using `.isNaN()` ;)  [**Tested working here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ppVGrv?editors=1111)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I finally got it, it did not work previously because the script I used was inside a jquery  script "$(document).ready(function(){" I finally discovered removed it and it works perfectly now. I also added localStorage.removeItem("scroll_y"); when the scroll has activated to remove the item from local storage so that the scroll variable is reset.